# Closed valley to open valley on clay shingle roof?

Tags: roof

My home is about 30 years old and has a clay tile roof. I was cleaning around a skylight yesterday and decided to take a look at the valleys.

1. The valleys are closed.
2. There are "W" formed valley pans.
3. The pans were packed with mud and debris because they used chunks of broken tile to sporadically support the shingles that "closed" the valley. There were numerous obstructions resting up against the "peak" of the pan.
4. The tiles are not nailed into place. I was able to carefully slide them up and out of the way, clean the pan, and then put them back into place.

My personal opinion is that this closed valley is a poor choice on roof that is supposed to last 50+ years. What I am wondering is if it is ok to "convert" this to an open valley by just leaving the tiles slid further up to expose a total of 4 - 6 inches of the pan. Then I think the rain would keep it clear. And it would be easier to pop up there once a year with a broom and a blower to double check it. Is there any reason, besides aesthetics, **not** to do this?

Comment: I just found out that batten extenders exist. Anyone have any thoughts on including those on a conversion to an open valley?